# jQuery Ajax load a certain div only?

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

Hi can someone help me how to specify in the first example that i want processing only a certian DIV like i can do with the "load" method insteasd of "ajax" long version?
thank you

```
// WITH EXTENDED VERSION, how to specify a div to be processed?
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  success: function(data) {
    $('#current-div').html(data);
    alert('Load was performed.');
  }
});

// WITH LOAD, it's ok|
$("a").click(function() {
  var myUrl = $(this).attr("href") + " #external-div";
  $("#current-div").load(myUrl);
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you're after is this?

```
$('#current-div').load('ajax/test.html');
alert('Load was performed.');
```